# Searching Database Management Software

Tags: database, export

I´ve been searching for a Software that I have seen a while ago.
The Software was more a framework for Databases than an actual Databasemanagement software, you could add and manipulate tables but the most important Part was, that embedded to the software was a file-editor, that could automatically be filled with data from the tables. The layout of the files could be adjusted in some matters. All of this was fully manageable with a gui, which made it possible to have team members without in depth knowlodge use it. The software was used for example to manage members and print out lists with members that had specific attributes with a specific layout.
If you have any suggestions what the name is or know a piece of software that has the same features, please let me know.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How old is this software? A few years? A decade? Windows? Linux? etc

Comment: I saw this software around 5 years ago on a Windows machine. I would need to guess the how old it is but it propably first appeard between 2005-2010. Its hard to decribe the UI because it has been a pretty long time ive seen it. It bascially had the possibility to create different projects, each project could have own tables and files. The editor for the files needed to be opened separately from a kind of hidden menu.